# does not translate VKcode to unicode

Tags: c++, winapi

everything works well with the English layout, but for example it does not output anything with the Russian one, and if you use count, not wcout, then just the code of the digit (prail)

what I need to do to make the code work. I need the code to be translated to unicode

```
MSG msg;
....
update(cursorPos, hWnd, &msg);
if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
{
TranslateMessage(&msg);
DispatchMessage(&msg);
}

void update(POINT pos, HWND hWnd, MSG* msg)
{

    if (msg->message == WM_KEYDOWN) {
    GetSymbolFromVK((msg->wParam)); 
    }   

}

WORD GetSymbolFromVK(WPARAM wParam)
{

    BYTE btKeyState[256] = {};
    HKL hklLayout = GetKeyboardLayout(0);
    WCHAR buff[32];
    WORD Symbol = NULL;
    GetKeyboardState(btKeyState);
    /*if ((ToAsciiEx(wParam, MapVirtualKey(wParam, 0), btKeyState, &Symbol, 0, hklLayout) == 1) &&
        (GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL) >= 0) && (GetKeyState(VK_MENU) >= 0))
        return Symbol;*/
    if ((ToUnicodeEx(wParam, MapVirtualKeyEx(wParam, 0, hklLayout), btKeyState, buff, 32, 0, hklLayout) &&
        (GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL) >= 0) && (GetKeyState(VK_MENU) >= 0)) == 1)
    {
        /*int nSize = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, (LPCCH)buff, -1, NULL, 0);
        MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, (LPCCH)buff, -1, *buff[0], nSize);*/
        std::wcout<<*buff <<std::endl;
    }
    return -1;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce the behavior using the code except I use *`OutputDebugString`* to print. [`ToUnicodeEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-tounicodeex) works well to *Translates the specified virtual-key code and keyboard state to the corresponding Unicode character or characters.*
[image]